# Do patella bones form in people born with the inability to walk?

Tags: human-anatomy, development, bone-biology

The **patella** is a [**sesamoid bone**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesamoid_bone) that typically doesn't completely from and ossify until ~3-6 years of age (e.g., [Source](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.414.9635&rep=rep1&type=pdf)). My long-standing understanding (supported by a claim in Saladin's college A&P textbook<sup>1</sup> sitting on my shelf) was that sesamoid bones form "in response to stress."

Well, I had a student in my anatomy class this morning ask me the titular question about people born with leg paralyses or other congenital issues preventing them from walking. To their point, **if such congenitally paralyzed people never walk and therefore never place stress on the knee via the quad tendon, would they ever form a sesamoid bone (i.e., the patella) in the knee?**

I've done some digging and found evidence of "nail patella syndrome" (e.g., [here](https://www.popsci.com/genetic-disorder-leaves-some-without-kneecaps/)) which results in people not forming a complete patella. However, I was unable to quickly narrow down any sources discussing **lack of patellar growth due to congenital leg paralysis.**

---

<sup>1.  Saladin, K. S. 2015. *Anatomy & Physiology: The Unity of form and function*. 7th edition. McGrawHill, Education, New York, NY</sup>

Answer (score 5):

**In mice, patella would form, but not separate from femur.**

[On the development of the patella](https://dev.biologists.org/content/142/10/1831):

> Previous studies have suggested a central role for mechanical load in
> the initiation of sesamoid development.
>
> Our finding that the patella initially forms as part of the femur and
> is later separated by joint formation led us to revisit the issue of
> mechanical contribution to patella development. To achieve this, we
> studied patella development in mutant embryos devoid of contracting
> muscles, as a result of the naturally occurring autosomal recessive
> mutation muscular dysgenesis (mdg; Cacna1s). These mice lack
> excitation-contraction coupling and, consequently, their skeletal
> muscles lack contractility.
>
> Histological analysis of sagittal sections of hindlimbs identified at
> E13.5, in both mutant and control littermates, the existence of
> patella progenitors, which were part of the femur. However, at E14.5,
> whereas in the control we observed joint formation between the patella
> and the femur, in mdg mutants this process was not detected.
> Consequently, at E16.5 the mutant patella was still part of the femur.
> These results suggest that, although muscle contraction does not
> affect patella initiation, it plays a crucial role later during the
> separation phase.

I know, you asked for human, but it is the only relevant information I found. However, while sources mention a role of physical stress in the calcification of sesamoid bones, the preceding formation of cartilage seems unaffected. Now, given the information that ossification occurs in mice without physical stress, I personally would conclude that the human patella would also calcify in paralyzed persons. Strictly, the question whether the patella forms, should be answered, if a non-detached patella counts.

Comment: Very good find! Thank you for this! +1. I will hold off accepting your answer, though, to see if anyone ever stumbles across any info regarding patella detachment, especially in humans. (I would have never thought such a topic was so difficult to research!)